# Pass data between viewmodels

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I think I am getting somewhere with mvc.
I have created a view that is bound to my view model that looks like this

```
public class CreatePurchaseViewModel
{
  public Order Order { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
  public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
  public bool OrderSent { get; set; }

}
```

I have also created another view model

```
public class ProductsViewModel
{
  public int ProductID { get; set; }
  public int OrderID { get; set; }
}
```

I have create a partial view that is bound to this viewmodel.

I am loading it from my view

```
@Html.Partial("_AddProductItem", new MVC_WireFrame.ViewModels.ProductsViewModel())
```

Now how do I get the items from my ProductsViewModel into my CreatePurchaseViewModel or is that not the correct way of doing things?

I can access the data from the ProductsViewModel in my controller like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult InsertProduct(string input)
{}
```

2 questions really, how do I pass the value into the other viewcontroller? and
how do I populate a list within the AddProduct partial view so I can show what products have been added?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you should not be passing data from one view model to another. You should create your view model classes in such a way that they contain all the required information for the view to display. It is the controller's responsibility to fill this information. Concerning you second question about the list, well you simply add a property which is of type `IEnumerable<T>` to this view model which will be filled by the controller and the view can show what products have been added. So think of what information your views require and add it to the view models as properties.

Comment: Thanks again Darin,
Can I update my CreatePurchaseViewModel viewmodel to contain a public List<ProductsViewModel> 

I then add all of the selected items into CreatePurchaseViewModel? my controller then handles the ProductsViewModel list.

Comment: @Diver, feel free to put whatever properties you need in the view models. That's what they are intended for: contain all information required by the view.

Comment: cool.....its starting to slowly make sense :)
From a client side point of view do I build up all of my ProductsViewModel objects in something like a hidden field for the httpPost?

Comment: @Diver Dan, if you want to persist them between requests then using hidden fields to store their values is one approach. Another approach is to store only an id into a hidden field which will be sent to the server and the server will use this id to re-fetch the values from your data store.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I will just need to do some research on how to store not only the id but also things like quantity. Perhaps building a json object with every button click than when I post back to the control I read the json.